# Can Ruby interface with r?

Tags: ruby, r

A friend needs to do some R programming for her PhD and since I'm a programmer, asked me to give her a hand.

So I took a look at some [r](http://www.r-project.org/) [related](http://www.programmingr.com/) [webstuff](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming) and discovered that you can interact with it through RPy (python) and statistics::R (perl).  Is there a way for Rubyists to hook into R?

Is there a dummy's guide to learning R (like a video series)?

Comment: My advice: in general, interfacing between languages is the road to hell, especially in terms of maintaining code. If the goal is R programming, then just learn R programming. Hooking into R from a more familiar language won't help, since you need to understand the R anyway.

Comment: Well, there is the excellent [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org) frameworks for python. The thinking is a bit closer to Ruby than learning an entirely new language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [RSRuby](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby) for accessing R functionality through Ruby.

As for a beginner's tutorial, try looking at ["R For Beginners"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf).  I found it helpful when I had to learn some basic R for a statistics course.

Comment: thanks for the RSRuby link and another thanks for the link to the beginners guide :)

Comment: RSRuby is okay for some applications, but I ended up dropping from my toolkit a while back. I actually found that it's often easier and quicker to write out your data to a file, pull it into R, calculate your statistics, then output another file.  The main problem is that the interface adds a lot of overhead, especially on large data sets.

Answer (score 13):

[This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sausheong/rubyand-r) summarises the alternatives.

#### Libraries

- [RinRuby](https://github.com/clbustos/rinruby/commits/master)
- [RSRuby](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby)

Both discussed in others' answers, both haven't been updated years.

#### [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) with Ruby client

Rserve is a Java TCP/IP server that the native Ruby client can connect to.

I've just tested out this approach and it's extremely easy.

```
sudo apt-get install -y r-base ruby-gems # Just in case...

sudo R
> install.packages("Rserve")
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve()

# (In another window - not sure how the 'daemon mode' operates exactly.

sudo gem install rserve-client

irb
> require "rserve"
> include Rserve
> c = Connection.new
> x = c.eval("R.version.string");
> puts x.as_string

R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14)
  => nil
```

#### [rApache](http://rapache.net/) and [Rook](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/Rook) (formerly "rrack")

rApache is a web application framework for R (just like Rails is for Ruby). I think Rook is a shim to allow rApache to work on non-Apache webservers. So the approach here (I think) is to run rApache and Rails side by side. Your Rails app can call rApache/Rook as needed to perform queries, or to hand over control for rendering graphs etc.

Answer (score 2):

[RinRuby](https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/) is another project that does the Ruby/R interface.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [Ruby client](http://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client) for Rserve.