# Best way to use R in Ruby

Tags: ruby, r, statistics, rubygems

I want to visualize some of my statistical caluclations in Ruby.

My problem is, that I can't find the right gem for that.

rsruby doesn't seem to be up-to-date and I can't install it in Ruby 1.9.2.

Do you know a way how to run the R commands in Ruby?

Comment: Rserve + http://rubygems.org/gems/rserve-simpler or http://opencpu.org/

Comment: Search for `[r] [ruby]`, this has been answered before...

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287265/r-statistical-package-gem-for-a-rails-application

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686439/can-ruby-interface-with-r/14722213#14722213

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I just saw this post and thought I should comment since I use R pretty extensively. If you are coming from an R background the best gem I have found is [Rinruby](https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/). The reason it is fantastic is because you don't interpret the commands in ruby, you use actual R code. For example:

```
require "rinruby"      
#Set all your variables in Ruby
n = 10
beta_0 = 1
beta_1 = 0.25
alpha = 0.05
seed = 23423
R.x = (1..n).entries
#Use actual R code to perform the analysis
R.eval <<EOF
  set.seed(#{seed})
  y <- #{beta_0} + #{beta_1}*x + rnorm(#{n})
  fit <- lm( y ~ x )
  est <- round(coef(fit),3)
  pvalue <- summary(fit)$coefficients[2,4]
EOF
```

On the Rinruby website I listed above there are some fantastic examples to get you started. Hope this helped.

-Sean

Comment: Sean, don't mince your words.  Do you think it RinRuby is fantastic or not?

Comment: @sean, is there a way to generate the graphs through the webpage instead of having them display in a R window?  I'm using the Gettysburg example from the library's website for testing this currently...

Comment: @daveomcd It's been awhile..., but can't you just just render to PNG as your graphic device instead of an R window and then display the PNG?

Comment: @bigtunacan yes I ended up saving it as a temporary png and the embedding in the page thanks!

Comment: What is the benefit of using R in ruby? Is it faster to execute this code using Rinruby versus just running it in R?

Comment: Definitely faster to just use R if you are doing stats stuff. You use r in ruby when you need to combine the two. My use case is that I execute the R code from inside ruby a ruby program to generate some visualizations that I then use/display elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

As @Hansi mentioned, [RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html) is the best way I've found to run R remotely. If you're using Ruby from a web-context especially, RServe can offer some nice benefits.

Best of all (in my mind), you don't get locked into any one programming framework, as there are RServe clients for a variety of languages including Java and C++. When using web-accessible platforms, you can even keep Rserve running on a separate host and route traffic over TCP/IP for added security.